# TypeError: tours.map is not a function. Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

I'm pulling data from a url. I print it on the screen and delete each one with a button. After there is no element left, a button appears on the screen. The function of this button is to capture data again. But when I press this button, I get the error I mentioned. Could someone explain what's going on here?

App.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Loading from './Loading'
import Tours from './Tours'

const url = 'https://course-api.com/react-tours-project'
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [tours, setTours] = useState([])

  const removeTour = (id) => {
    setTours(tours.filter(tour => tour.id!==id))
  }

  const fetchTours = async () => {
    setTours(true)
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url)
      setTours(response.data)
      setLoading(false)

    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{ 
    fetchTours()  
  },[])

  if(loading){
    return(
      <main>
        <Loading/>
      </main>
    )
  }
  if (tours.length === 0) {
    return(
      <main>
        <div className='title'>
          <h2>no tours left</h2>
          <button onClick={fetchTours} className='btn'>Fetch Data Again</button>
        </div>

      </main>
    )
  }

  return(
      <main>
        <Tours tours={tours} removeTour={removeTour}/>
      </main>
    )
}

export default App
```

Tours.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Tour from './Tour';

const Tours = (props) => {
  const {tours,removeTour} = props
  return (
    <section>
      <div className='title'>
        <h2>ours tours</h2>
        <div className='underline'></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {tours.map((item) => {
          return <Tour key={item.id} {...item} removeTour={removeTour}/>
        }) }
      </div>
    </section>

  )
};

export default Tours;
```

Tour.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Tour = (props) => {
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false)
  const { id, name, info, image, price,removeTour } = props
  return (
    <article className="single-tour">
    <img src={image} alt={name} />
    <footer>
      <div className="tour-info">
        <h4>{name}</h4>
        <h4 className="tour-price">${price}</h4>
      </div>
      <p>{readMore ? info : `${info.substring(0,180)}...`}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setReadMore(!readMore)}>{readMore ? 'show less':'read more'}</button>
      <button className="delete-btn" onClick={() => removeTour(id)}>
        not interested
      </button>
    </footer>
  </article>
  )
};

export default Tour;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is because of the below code in your `fetchTours`

```
 setTours(true)
```

I don't think its needed . Please remove it. Also i have changed the initial state of the loading to be `false` . so that if you delete all the items and click on `Fetch Data Again` you will see the `<Loading />` getting displayed again .

Updated code , you can replace your code with this

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [tours, setTours] = useState([]);

const removeTour = (id) => {
  setTours(tours.filter((tour) => tour.id !== id));
};

const fetchTours = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    setTours(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```

Added the `finally` block in the try-catch instead of changing the `setLoading` in both the `then` and `catch` . Because `finally` block runs irrespective of whether your request is success or failure .

[finally -mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_finally-block)